# linux + huge of sshd: root@notty from ps

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, sshd, ps

we cant access to one of our RHEL server VIA `ssh`

as

```
ssh $remote_machine
Last login: Sun Jul 24 12:37:25 2022 from  ...... 

**login is HANG**
```

also when we did `ssh $remote_machine "uptime"`

we saw huge load CPU average - `86.3` ( while we have only `8 CPU` on that machine )

what we identify until now is that we seen many `sshd: root@notty` when doing `ssh remote_machine "ps -ef | grep ssh"`

example

```
ssh $remote_machine "ps -ef| grep sshd"
root        685      1  0 May28 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root        977      1  0 May28 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root       1171      1  0 Jul16 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root       1719      1  0 Jul13 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root       2273      1  0 Jun08 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root       3135      1  0 May30 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root       3265      1  0 Jun02 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root       5154      1  0 12:56 ?        00:00:00 bash -c ps -ef| grep sshd
root       5169   5154  0 12:56 ?        00:00:00 grep sshd
root       6528      1  0 12:57 ?        00:00:00 bash -c ps -ef| grep sshd
root       6542   6528  0 12:57 ?        00:00:00 grep sshd
root       6995      1  0 12:57 ?        00:00:00 bash -c ps -ef| grep sshd
root       7009   6995  0 12:57 ?        00:00:00 grep sshd
root       7587 129674  0 12:57 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root       7656 129674  1 12:57 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root       7723 129674  1 12:57 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root       7751 129674  0 12:57 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root       7759   7751  0 12:57 ?        00:00:00 bash -c ps -ef| grep sshd
root       7773   7759  0 12:57 ?        00:00:00 grep sshd
root      34015      1  0 Jul20 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      36646      1  0 Jun14 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      39014      1  0 Jul08 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      39710      1  0 May25 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      40111      1  0 Jul22 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      44437      1  0 Jun21 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      44573      1  0 Jul14 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      45549      1  0 Jul17 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      45886      1  0 May21 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      45934      1  0 May31 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      49840      1  0 Jul20 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      52583      1  0 Jun09 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty
root      52785      1  0 Jun14 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@notty

.
.
.
.
.
```

we try to kill the pid's of that sshd as

```
ssh  $remote_machine "kill -9  685  977 ...."
```

but still there are huge of sshd: `root@notty` lines from `ps -ef` on remote machine

so the last option is just reboot machine

but can we do something in order to avoid such as huge sshd process as we get on our machine?

Comment: Are those `sshd: root@notty` processes using CPU or are they just dead sessions that were never closed, bumping up the load because of unclouded connections?  That kind of sshd is typically the result of a root login that didn’t require a TTY, such as an sftp connection or directly calling a remote process.  Do you use Ansible or a similar tool?

Comment: yes we are using ansible for installation and configuration